# Sum elements in a vector without specific element and varying index

Tags: r

I want to calculate in a vector the sum of each element without a specific one. The element to remove is going to change at each calculation.

Quick example :

```
vect <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
```

What I want is :

```
for (i in 1:length(vect)){
    print(sum(vect[-i]))
}
```

But I would like to avoid for-loop because they are quite slow.
Any solution with an `apply` function or vectorized calculation ?

Comment: `apply` solutions are also loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all too complicated.

```
sum(vect) - vect
# [1] 6 6 5 4
```

is what you want.

The sum of a vector except for an element is the (sum of the vector) - (an element).

Comment: Hahaha, seeing this solution all the others seam stupid. +1

Comment: The other answers are clever, it's just the problem was stated to sound more complicated than it is.

Comment: And it makes the question not that relevant. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colSums` as follows:

```
rev(colSums(matrix(rep(a,3),3)))
```

Results in

```
> rev(colSums(matrix(rep(a,3),3)))
[1] 6 6 5 4
```

Comment: Ok, I would put `length(vect) - 1` instead of 3 to be more general. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is `rollsum` from `library(RcppRoll)`.  It should be fast (not as fast as @Gregor's solution, but should beat all the other solutions).

```
library(RcppRoll)
head(roll_sum(c(vect, vect), k=3),-1)[-1]
#[1] 6 6 5 4
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(254)
 v1 <- sample(1:9, 1e5, replace=TRUE)
 system.time(vapply(1:length(v1), function(i) sum(v1[-i]), 1))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 1.734   0.007   1.748 
 system.time(sum(v1)-v1)
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #     0       0       0 
system.time(head(roll_sum(c(v1,v1), n= length(v1)-1), -1)[-1])
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.099   0.000   0.099
```

Couldn't complete @Flo0's solution as I got an error for allocating vector of size 37 GB.